# Does Angular Hydration work with Prerender

Tags: angular, angular-universal, hydration, pre-rendering

I want to use client hydration with prerender in an Angular Universal app, but it doesn't seem to work.

I have an Angular Universal app setup and when I run `npm run prerender`, everything works as expected.  No matter how many times I refresh, the same static version that was prerendered is served.  So all is good.

But if I enable client hydration by putting this in `app.module.ts`:
`providers: [provideClientHydration()]`

it starts rendering on the server every time I refresh.

Is this expected or is it a bug?  I'm using Angular 16.2.2.

Comment: Would be interested in this as well. For this to work, each route need to hydrate the state in the generation process as well.